# Finding pixels covered by an oval in Java Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, area

I'm creating a graphical display to show whether a user is approaching a **danger zone.** For this i'm using a display similar to that of an archery board. The idea is to start in the center, but as the user gets closer to the danger zone enter the orange zone. And once the user breaks the 'safety threshold' enter the red zone. My idea is to draw a point on the board depending on what value the user gives me.
To draw this board I do the following.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600); //set screen to white
g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillOval(250, 250, 175, 175); //draw outerlayer of board as red
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.drawOval(250, 250, 175, 175);//give this red an outline
    g2d.setColor(Color.orange);
    g2d.fillOval(275, 275, 125, 125); //draw innerlayer as orange
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.drawOval(275, 275, 125, 125);//give this orange an outline
    g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    g2d.fillOval(300, 300, 75, 75); //draw innermost layer as green
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.drawOval(300, 300, 75, 75); //give the green an outline
```

First of all I could probably improve this, but that's not the main issue for now.

Instead my issue is finding exactly the pixels covered by each part of the board.
 **I've been using x+(width/2), y+(height/2) to get the center point**
Thus using:

```
g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("X"), 338, 338);
```

To draw the center point of my **green oval**. This doesn't seem overly accurate but anyway.
I thought I would be able to simply give the outer edge as the x,y co-ords and the inner edge as the x+height, y+width co-ords as so:

```
g2d.drawOval(500, 500, 75, 75);
g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("X"), 537, 537); //centre???
g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("X"), 575, 575); //inneredge?x+width, y+height
g2d.drawString(String.valueOf("X"), 500, 500); //outer edge x+y co-ords
```

However, I think due to the oval shape this doesn't work.

I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to find the pixel range that each oval covers.

EDIT: Below is the board that i'm using, is it possible to find the pixel range for each color(Red,Orange,Green)? 
[image: Example of the board]

Comment: Sorry, this is quite unclear. Could you maybe draw a sketch with what you are trying to measure/display, and where you are currently?

Comment: I've added what I currently have. I'm trying to work out the borders for each Oval. Hence the X,Y,Z,Z,A etc.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "work out the borders"? What is wrong with the letters X, Y, Z, Z, A? Should they be located on each border? Or elsewhere? Why is A located on the vertical of the center? I count 3 borders but 5 letters + X. What do you mean by "pixel range"? Is it a distance? From what point to what point?... Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: Sorry. I was just playing around with random letters. Basically I would like to find out the 'area' per say of each oval. But not actually the area, like a range of pixels for each oval. For a square I think this would be much easier it would be xstart->xEnd and yTop->yBottom e.g. 100,400-100,400, which would cover every pixel in said square... However, for a oval I cant quite figure out how to do this.

Comment: Basically users will be measured on how much force they put on an object. If this force is safe they will be in the green, but as it increases it will head outwards, so I need different pixel 'spots' for each oval. I could make it simple by finding say 5 spots in each oval myself, but If there is a way to find a range of pixels in each oval it would make it much more 'fluid'

Comment: Still unclear... So you "measure" the "force users put on an object": That gives you a **number**? You want to convert this number into a **point** that you draw on the target? The point should be located close to the center if the number is small, and far from the center if the number is large? What about the "direction" (north,east,west,south)? Should it be random?

Comment: Yes. Basically the foce will be an int from 0-250 lets say. The range of 0-75 will be green, 75-175 orange, 175+ red. However 0 should be in the exact center of the green, whereas 50 even though still green should be closer to the orange. (same with orange/red..) The logic behind this will be relatively easy. It's just managing to get a range of pixels to place these values on to. The program will refresh every time a new value comes in and remove the previous point. Imagine it a bit like radar. The direction Is random yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding a bit more what you wanted, here is the trick (using [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)):

```
int force = ...; // from 0 to 250
int radius = ...; // radius of the target (50 for example)
int centerX = ...; // X-coordinate of the center of the target
int centerY = ...; // Y-coordinate of the center of the target
double direction = Math.toRadians(Math.random() * 360); // a random angle between 0° and 360°
double x = (force * radius / 250.0d) * Math.cos(direction) + centerX; // X-coordinate of the new point
double y = (force * radius / 250.0d) * Math.sin(direction) + centerY; // Y-coordinate of the new point
Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x,y); // Then you can plot this point on your target
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a certain size oval I need to use for this (e.g. 250 as that is the scale of the force?)? The scale of the point is going way outside my current zones. Another issue is it seems that Java draws an oval as a square, e.g. point x,y is the top left white space outside the oval. I believe my program sees this white space as part of the circle.

Comment: Oh, yes, you should apply a scaling factor on `force`, so that the maximum force corresponds to the outter border: Multiply `force` by `radius/250.0`, where `radius` is the radius of the target in pixels.

Answer (score 3):

All of your ovals appear to be circles.  So, let's create a Circle model class.

You would call the draw method from a JPanel paintComponent method.

You would call the contains method when you want to see if a point is inside or on the edge of a circle.

You would keep track of all of the circles in a List, so you can maintain the order of the circles.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle {

    private final int radius;
    private final Color color;
    private final Point location;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius, Color color) {
        this.location = new Point(x, y);
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        double distance = Point.distance(x, y, location.x, location.y);
        double radiusD = radius;
        if (radiusD >= distance) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(location.x - radius, location.y - radius, radius + radius,
                radius + radius);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a concrete `Ellipse2D` for each zone. Then you can use `g2d.fill()` to draw the zone. Since an `Ellipse2D` is also a `Shape`, you can use the `contains(Point2D p)` method to check if a point is in bounds. Since the circles overlap, you'll have to check them in front-to-back order.

Comment: Thank you, I've change my code to use Ellipse2D and now I can check if a pixel is within each oval which is useful.

 I'm now trying to find a more efficient way to get a range inside the borders rather than manually finding a large set, but I assume this will be tricky as of the shape? i.e. I would like a pixel range for each oval. E.G. green  could be 50,50- 125,125 red 125,125-175,175. But I think I may be misunderstanding the way pixels work in shapes

Comment: You can use `Math. hypot()` to get the distance between to points.